# How to expand a big query table with n rows?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a set of values and I need to add rows with nulls (it is not always the same amount of rows). For example, let's say the value data has three rows with values 1, 2, 3 and I need to have 5 rows in total. What would be the simplest way to get a table with 1, 2, 3, NULL, NULL?

I already have a way to do it, but it involves using a bigger table that already has NULLs and always has more rows than required, then joining in the number of rows needed, then using ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION BY and ORDER BY and finally filtering out those rows that have row number higher than the required number of rows. But this is not very efficient and it seems to me like there should be a simpler way.